# Marginal Probability of $X$ & $Z$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Let $X$ & $Z$ be real valued r.v.'s with absolutely continuous joint distribution, whose density is given by:

$$f_{(X,Z)}= e^{-z}\mathbf{1}_{\{0\leq x \leq z\}}$$

Find the marginal densities of $X$ and $Z$.

I know the marginal densities are given by:

$$f_X = \int{f_{(X,Z)}}dz$$
$$f_Z = \int{f_{(X,Z)}}dx$$

My confusion is caused by the indicator function in the joint density. What are my boundaries for each integral? Do I have to "ignore" $x$ and integrate from $0$ to $z$ for $dz$? What do I do for $dx$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, for $f_X$ I would then fix $z$ and integrate from $0$ to $z$ and get $1-e^{-z}$?

Comment: For $f_{X}$, you are fixing $x$ and integrating with respect to $z.$ Given a fixed value of $x \geq 0$, the integrand is nonzero only when $z \geq x$, in which case it is equal to $e^{-z}.$ So you can integrate $e^{-z}$ from $x$ to $\infty.$

Comment: Oh, so for $f_Z$ I fix $z\geq 0$ and see that the integrand is nonzero for $0\leq x \leq z$ and integrate $e^{-z}$ from $0$ to $z$ w.r.t. $x$? @Austin80

Comment: @MathematicalMoose exactly.

Comment: @Austin80 Thank you so much!

Comment: @Austin80 one last question, so integrating and finding then, for example $f_X = e^{-x} - 1$, What is the domain for the $x$? Is it from $0$ to $z$?

Comment: $f_X$ should not be $e^{-x}-1$, rather $e^{-x}$

Comment: @MathLover you're completely right, sorry. Somehow I mistakenly thought $e^{-\infty} = 1$